# 'Let all go' meaning?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-structure

I have purchased a domain named with 'letallgo', because 'LETITGO' was not available. Now I want to know how does it different from 'letitgo'. Is it mean the same as 'letitgo'. I know *it* and *all* has lot difference. Is it worthy?

Comment: 'Let it go' is a common idiom. 'Let all go' may be sensible grammatically, but it sounds very strange to this native ear. 'Let it all go' would sound a lot more natural, if you wanted to talk about letting multiple things go.

Comment: Aside: Bear in mind that when it comes to internet domains, all actual meaning will become swamped by whatever you use it for. After all, what did "google", "flckr", or "youtube" even mean before those services came into being? So the difference between "it" and "all" is probably irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually 3 phrases: “let it go”, “let it all go”, and “let all go”. “Let it go” usually refers to  a thing that has already been mentioned, which should be let go. (Or [this song from the movie *Frozen*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=moSFlvxnbgk).) “Let it all go” means that you should let everything go, or that there are multiple things (that have already been mentioned) that should be let go. “Let all go” is sometimes the same as the former (*first*) “let it all go”, but it more often means that you should unwind and let yourself go. “Let all go” is also slightly less formal in some cases.

Sources: Oxford Dictionaries

1. [let it go (or pass)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/let_it_go_(or_pass)) (redirected from "let it go")
2. [let oneself go](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/let_oneself_go) (redirected from "let all go")